# Redundant buttons on empty state

Tags: usability

For empty state screen, which option is better?

**Option 1:**
Have two identical buttons, one in the normal place (next to heading), and one next to the text that explains what should the user do

pros: button next to text makes the action easy to find

cons: redundancy can confuse users, they can think that these are different actions (although the design and text is exactly the same)

**Option 2:**
Have only one button next to the header, where it will be later on as well.

pros: cleaner screen

Cons: there is a chance that the users will miss the CTA

This is for a desktop system that the users use on a daily basis,
I could not find any clear reference for option 1, and I am against using arrows for pointing at the top button

[image]

Comment: I personally see no problem with the redundant case, but if your concern with the second option (that users won't notice the button in the header) is valid, that would imply that they may not notice it in the "non-empty" state and that perhaps you should move/alter the button in the header.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while since you posted this question, so not sure how actively helpful my response will be now but I thought to give my 2 cents on it too.

Agreeing with jazZRo and adding further points to their response, there exist a set of principles and research formed by psychologists that could be useful to you for future reference when it comes to visual attention and perception of objects.

Some key points to be aware of in your case:

- Our **visual focus** tends to be limited, we cannot view everything on a page in one go. By focusing our attention on a specific section on the page, that section becomes sharper, while the rest of the area surrounding it becomes less vivid.  Hence if we make a testable hypothesis that the user's attention will be drawn to the empty state image/copy area, regardless whether we (as designers) think a position of an element is obvious, there's a higher chance that the user will miss the CTA on the heading.
- People tend to group together any elements that appear in close **proximity** - thinking that they are related. In this case by having the CTA close to the empty state visual area there's a higher chance for the user to make the assumption that the action on that button is relevant to it.
- Lastly, people start reading from top to bottom and by positioning the CTA below the empty state section it gives a sense of **continuity**. It does not interrupt their natural flow by searching around the page for an action to take.

In general, when you study visual attention, these questions come in handy as a guide (taken from the article referenced below):

- "What visual information determines the target of the next eye movement?"
- "What visual information determines when the eyes move?"
- "What information is combined across eye movements to form a stable
  representation of the environment?"

These articles expand further on the points I've raised above:

- Gestalt principles https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/topics/gestalt-principles
- Visual attention https://thepsychologist.bps.org.uk/volume-25/edition-12/visual-attention-%E2%80%93-fresh-look

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest **option 3**?

Show the button only there where it is mentioned. It will cost less effort to understand the intention of the page and where to find the button.
On that page, remove the CTA from the header. You can add it back on other pages as a reminder. But you have to be sure that it is clear to users what the CTA means in that context; the header on any page.

Anyway, showing the button twice will probably confuse some people and is not needed at all.

[image]